# Is there a way to synchronize sections of different Word documents?

Tags: documentation, ms-word, documentation-generation

I'm working on how my company does documentation (especially programming documentation).  I'd like to be able to synchronize sections of different Word documents, such that if a section in one document changes, the change is reflected in the other document, and vice versa.  Is there a way to do this with Word, and if not, is there some word processing program that is good at this?

Comment: What kind of "synchronisation" are we talking about? Does it involve copying changes? Can you give an example, please?

Comment: As an example, if I had [section 1] in document A, and document B is synced to [section 1] of document A, if I typed "Hello World" in document A, and then opened document B, I'd see "Hello World" in that section.  If I then made a change in document B, and opened document A, I'd see the change, and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use the Master and Subdocument features built-in with Word? It's exactly for your kind of situation.

Answer (score 7):

I appreciate this is an old question, but Google brought me here.

This can be done (at least on Word 2016, other versions not tested) one-way as follows:

1. In the source document, select the text you want to synchronise, and on the `Insert` tab, click `Bookmark` in the `Links` section.
2. Type a name for the bookmark (no spaces allowed), and click `Add`.
3. Save the document.
4. Open the document where you want to duplicate the text ("destination document").
5. On the `Insert` tab, click the drop-down arrow next to `Object` (in the `Text` section), then click `Text from File...`.
6. Browse to find the source document, and select it.
7. Click `Range...`.
8. Type the bookmark name you entered in step 2, and click OK.
9. Click the drop-down next to the `Insert` button, and click `Insert as Link`.

When you want to edit the text, proceed as follows.

1. Modify the source document as required, and save.
2. Update the field in the destination document with one of the following methods:

   - Right-click on the text and click `Update Field`.
   - Click on the text and press <kbd>F9</kbd>.
   - To update all fields in a document, Press <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> then <kbd>F9</kbd>.

Comment: It there a way to have two ways sync?

Answer (score 3):

You can always make section 1 in your example above a third word document and then insert it into Document A and B (Insert > Object) and make the object linked to the file, so it will load changes each time you open A or B.

Comment: It seems like it imports it as a picture, and if it grows longer than one page, it gets chopped off.  I can import it as text, but that's more like a copy and paste, which isn't what I'm going for.